# Proof general state space similarity transformation to controllable canonical form

Tags: linear-transformations, control-theory, linear-control

Given a state space model of the form,

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A\,x + B\,u \\
y &= C\,x + D\,u
\end{align} \tag{1}
$$

however I think that this would also apply to a discrete time model.

Assuming that this state space model is controllable, I would like to find a nonsingular similarity transform $z=T\,x$, which would transform the state space to the following model,

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{z} &= \underbrace{T\,A\,T^{-1}}_{\bar{A}}\,z + \underbrace{T\,B}_{\bar{B}}\,u \\
y &= \underbrace{C\,T^{-1}}_{\bar{C}}\,z + \underbrace{D}_{\bar{D}}\,u
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$

such that it is in the [controllable canonical form](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Standard_Forms#Controllable_Canonical_Form) with,

$$
\bar{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
-a_n & -a_{n-1} & \cdots & -a_2 & -a_1
\end{bmatrix} \tag{3a}
$$

$$
\bar{B} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} \tag{3b}
$$

---

When $A$ is in the [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Standard_Forms#Jordan_Form), with Jordan blocks of at most size one by one (so no of diagonal terms),

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n
\end{bmatrix} \tag{4}
$$

with at most [algebraic multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity) of one. The states of matrix $(3a)$ can be seen as integrals of the next state and the last state a linear combination of the previous ones, therefore it can be shown that similarity transforms of the form,

$$
T = \left[\begin{array}{c c}
\alpha_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_1^2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_1^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} &
\alpha_2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_2^2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_2^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} & \cdots &
\alpha_n \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \lambda_n \\ \lambda_n^2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}\right] \tag{5}
$$

would bring $(4)$ to $(3a)$. The values for $\alpha_i$ can be solved for using $\bar{B}=T\,B$ and $(3b)$, when defining $B$ as,

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n
\end{bmatrix} \tag{6}
$$

then this equality can be written as,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\
\lambda_1\,b_1 & \lambda_2\,b_2 & \cdots & \lambda_n\,b_n \\
\lambda_1^2\,b_1 & \lambda_2^2\,b_2 & \cdots & \lambda_n^2\,b_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
\lambda_1^{n-1}\,b_1 & \lambda_2^{n-1}\,b_2 & \cdots & \lambda_n^{n-1}\,b_n
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} \tag{7}
$$

It can be noted that in this case the matrix in equation $(7)$ is the same as the transpose of the [controllability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability#Continuous_linear_time-invariant_.28LTI.29_systems),

$$
\mathcal{C} = \begin{bmatrix}B & A\,B & A^2B & \cdots & A^{n-1}B\end{bmatrix} \tag{8}
$$

so the solution to equation $(7)$ can also be written as,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n
\end{bmatrix} = \mathcal{C}^{-T}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} \tag{9a}
$$

$$
\vec{\alpha} = \mathcal{C}^{-T}
\bar{B} \tag{9b}
$$

The transpose of $T$ can, similar to equation $(7)$, also be written as,

$$
T^T = \begin{bmatrix}\vec{\alpha} & A\,\vec{\alpha} & A^2\vec{\alpha} & \cdots & A^{n-1}\vec{\alpha}\end{bmatrix} \tag{10}
$$

or if define a new vector $\vec{v}$ as the transpose of $\vec{\alpha}$ and substitute $\vec{\alpha}$ for the right hand side of equation $(9b)$,

$$
\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \mathcal{C}^{-1} \tag{11a}
$$

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{v} \\
\vec{v}\, A \\
\vec{v}\, A^2 \\
\vdots \\
\vec{v}\, A^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} \tag{11b}
$$

From this expression it can also be seen that if $\mathcal{C}$ is not full-rank, then such a transformation would not exist.

After some testing it seems that this expression also seem to hold for any $A$ and $B$, as long as $\mathcal{C}$ is full-rank/invertible, but in that case equation $(10)$ should contain $A^T$ instead of $A$ (but when using equation $(4)$, then $A=A^T$). However I do not know how I could go about proving that this is always the case.

---

Also a small side question: How could one define this transformation when $B$ is of size $n$ by $m$, with $m>1$? I suspect that in the controllable canonical form $\bar{B}$ should be of the form,

$$
\bar{B} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix} \tag{12}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single-input system the transformation that yields the controller canonical form is 
$$T=\left[\matrix{q\\qA\\ \vdots\\qA^{n-1}}\right]$$
where $q$ is the last row of the controllability matrix inverse i.e.
$$\mathcal{C}^{-1}=\left[\matrix{X\\ \hline q}\right]$$
This property ensures that 
$$qA^{i-1}b=\begin{cases}0,\quad i=1,\cdots,n-1\\ 1,\quad i=n \end{cases}$$
which can be used along with the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to  prove that 
$$Tb=\left[\matrix{qb \\ \vdots \\ qA^{n-2}b \\qA^{n-1}b}\right]=\left[\matrix{0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\1}\right]=\bar{B}$$
$$TA=\left[\matrix{qA \\ \vdots \\ qA^{n-1} \\qA^{n}}\right]=\left[\matrix{qA \\ \vdots \\ qA^{n-1} \\-q\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{n-i+1}A^{i-1}}\right]=\left[\matrix{0  & 1 & 0& \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\-a_n & -a_{n-1} & -a_{n-2}& \cdots & -a_1}\right]\left[\matrix{q \\ qA\\ \vdots \\ qA^{n-2} \\qA^{n-1}}\right]=\bar{A}T$$

---

For the multiple input case $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ the situation is more complex. The calculation involves the so called **controllability indices** $\mu_1,\mu_2,\cdots,\mu_m$ and  $\bar{B}$ is of the form
$$\bar{B}=\left[\matrix{0  & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\0  & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 1 & * & * & \cdots & *\\\hline 0  & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\0  & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & * & \cdots & *\\\hline \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\\hline 0  & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\0  & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1}\right] $$
where $*$ denotes a not necessarily zero element. The $m$ nonzero rows of $\bar{B}$ are the  $\mu_1,\mu_1+\mu_2,\cdots,\mu_1+\mu_2+\cdots+\mu_m$ rows. For more details I suggest you to consult the book [Antsaklis and Michel, "A linear systems primer"](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817644604) .

Comment: I think I understand the proof for $\bar{B}$, but I will have to take a closer look for $\bar{A}$. But how would you calculate $\mathcal{C}^{-1}$ when $m>1$, since then $\mathcal{C}$ is not a square matrix, or do you then need to use a different definition for $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @fibonatic You extract a new $n\times n$ matrix $\bar{\mathcal{C}}$ from $\mathcal{C}$ which is of dimension $n\times nm$ through a proper selection of $n$ linear independent columns of $\mathcal{C}$. Its form is $\bar{\mathcal{C}}=[\matrix{b_1 & Ab_1 & \cdots & A^{\mu_1-1}b_1 & b_2 & Ab_2&\cdots & A^{\mu_2-1}b_2 & \cdots & A^{\mu_m-1}b_m}]$ with $b_1,\cdots,b_m$ the columns of $B$.