# How to find a transformation matrix which will make the system a chain of integrators?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, optimal-control

Consider a system of the form 
$$\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)+\phi(t)+D(t)$$ 
I have 
$$\dot{x}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
-p_1 &G_b  & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0& -p_2 & p_3 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & -p_4 & p_5 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & -p_6 &p_6 \\ 
 0&  0& 0 & 0 & -p_6
\end{bmatrix}x(t)+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}u(t)+\begin{bmatrix}
-x_1(t)x_2(t)\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}D(t)$$
Where $\phi(t)$ is a lumped nonlinearity of the system and $D(t)$ is a disturbance acting from outside. I want to convert the system of the form
$$\dot{Z}_{i}=Z_{i+1}+\text{maybe nonlinearities and disturbances}, i=1,2,...,r-1 \\\dot{Z}_{r}=u+\text{maybe some function oif states}$$
i.e 
$$\dot{Z_1}=Z_2 \\ \dot{Z_2}=Z_3 \\ \cdots \\\dot{Z_r}=f(Z_1,...,Z_r,t,)+u$$
How to find a transformation matrix to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single input system the similarity transformation which transforms the system into its controllable canonical form is given by

$$
\vec{v}^\top = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B & B\, A & B\, A^2 & \cdots & B\, A^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}, \tag{1}
$$

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{v}^\top \\
\vec{v}^\top A \\
\vec{v}^\top A^2 \\
\vdots \\
\vec{v}^\top A^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}
$$

So using the transformation $z(t) = T\,x(t)$ gives

$$
\dot{z} = T\,A\,T^{-1} z(t) + T\,B\,u(t) + T\,\phi(t) + T\,D(t), \tag{3}
$$

where $(T\,A\,T^{-1}, T\,B)$ will be in the controllable canonical form.

If you would like to know more about how to derive this then you can look at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1960439).